# Booting a copied / imported VBox VM fails with error "System file could not be recovered"

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed Ubuntu 21.4 Desktop in my PC in a VirtualBox and copied the VM files to another PC. When I added the VM and I select the copied VM file then when booting the system starts to boot but after a while it gives me a white screen with the message:

`Something went wrong! The system file could not be recovers, try contact your Administrator.`

**Note:** I have tried to export VM, and then importing VM to the new PC but it gives me the same issue.
VirualBox is the same in both PCs.

Comment: I export the VM from VirtualBox itself and import it from the same.
File>export Appliance.
File>import Appliance.

Comment: Yes the VirualBox is the same in both PCs.

Comment: Did you shut down the VM first? idk if it affects VirtualBox but it does affect other VMs.

Comment: Yes I did shut down the VM.

Comment: Also I have Ubuntu 21.04 and I installed it to my PC and I copied it to the same PC and It works. 
But Ubuntu Desktop and also Fedora 33 Workstation has the same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but the last comment doesn't make much sense. Could you please clarify it? "Installing" and "creating a VM" are two entirely different concepts. What do you mean "installed and copied to the same PC", exactly? What do you mean with Ubuntu and Fedora having "the same problem" - if you create Ubu or Fed VM, export them and import to another PC you see same issue booting them up? Or you have same issue if you boot the VM on VBox running on Ubuntu or Fedora host? What's your host OS? Please do not answer in comments, edit your question to update or clarify the information.